# Regex or Try Catch to Validate Double - Best Performance

Tags: asp.net, regex, vb.net, try-catch

I'm having some variables passed over from the client side to the server. One of the variables should be received as a double but occasionally we get some string or null variables through from the client side that throws an exception.

My question is, from a performance aspect is it better to wrap the variable in a try, catch and apply a default on failure:

```
        Dim expectDouble As Double
        Try
            expectDouble = Request.Form("pastFromClient")
        Catch ex As Exception
            expectDouble = 0 'Default to zero
        End Try
```

Or to initially treat all incoming variables as string objects and run them against a regex?

```
        Dim expectDouble As Double
        If Regex.IsMatch(Request.Form("pastFromClient").toString, "^\d{1,}\.{0,1}\d{0,4}$") Then
            expectDouble = Request.Form("pastFromClient")
        Else
            expectDouble = 0 'Default to zero
        End If
```

The latter option may seem a little obscure but I've always felt uneasy having try, catch statements everywhere.

Comment: There should be `TryParse` function, which returns True/False http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/994c0zb1.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably the most important point first, you should set [`OPTION STRICT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcd4xwzs%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to `ON` generally. Then your code would not even copile what is a good thing.

It would not compile because `Request.Form` returns a string but `expectDouble`  is a `Double`. A string is *not* convertible to double implicitely.

You should use [`Double.Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.parse.aspx) or in this case [`Double.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.tryparse.aspx). Performance is not the main reason but failure safety and readability.

```
Dim expectDouble As Double
If Double.TryParse(Request.Form("pastFromClient"), expectDouble) Then
   ' here you have the value of expectDouble '
End If
```

Comment: I accidentally turned on OPTION STRICT a while back and was immediately swamped in VS warnings. I think I'd need a week to get through them all, but probably worth doing long term! Thanks for the input, very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Regexes are generally slow, as are Try/Catch blocks. In this case I would take the 2nd approach but I would not use Regexes.

Answer (score 0):

As Tim correctly points out implicit conversion should be avoided, in this instance you can perform your operation in one line so that the following

```
 Dim expectDouble As Double
 If Regex.IsMatch(Request.Form("pastFromClient").toString, "^\d{1,}\.{0,1}\d{0,4}$") Then
    expectDouble = Request.Form("pastFromClient")
 Else
    expectDouble = 0 'Default to zero
 End If
```

turns into

```
Dim expectDouble As Double
If NOT Double.TryParse(Request.Form("pastFromClient"), expectDouble) Then expectDouble = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

The others are correct.  You want to do the casting yourself explicitly.  Also, your normal program flow should never depend on an exception being caught.  There's a reason they are called "exceptions".

Here's how you can do it on one line using the ternary operator:

```
Dim expectDouble As Double = If(Double.TryParse(Request.Form("pastFromClient"), expectDouble), expectDouble, 0)
```

If the value passed into the form is a valid double, then expectDouble will hold that value; otherwise, it defaults to zero.  You can change the zero to some other default value if you need to.